# How do I include the hpp profile while building the interfaces in ROS2 Humble?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I am doing a robotic object where it needs three nodes.

First node is camera node which its function is to capture frames from camera and then publish those frames on a topic.

Second node will be a detection node which it will subscribe to the topic published by the first node, then process the information to AI model. then the detected objects will be send to third nodes via msg.

I am going to use the interface in ROS2 to send the  message from the second node to third node. I followed the instructions from this [documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html).

However, I get these errors:

```
Starting >>> custom_interfaces
 stderr: custom_interfaces                             
In file included from /home/wwl/test_ws/src/build/custom_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c/custom_interfaces/msg/detail/detected_object__functions.h:19,
                 from /home/wwl/test_ws/src/build/custom_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c/custom_interfaces/msg/detail/detected_object__functions.c:4:
/home/wwl/test_ws/src/build/custom_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c/custom_interfaces/msg/detail/detected_object__struct.h:22:10: fatal error: custom_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.h: No such file or directory
   22 | #include "custom_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/build.make:105: CMakeFiles/custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/rosidl_generator_c/custom_interfaces/msg/detail/detected_object__functions.c.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:213: CMakeFiles/custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /home/wwl/test_ws/src/build/custom_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/custom_interfaces/msg/detected_object__type_support.cpp:7:
/home/wwl/test_ws/src/build/custom_interfaces/rosidl_generator_cpp/custom_interfaces/msg/detail/detected_object__struct.hpp:20:10: fatal error: custom_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp: No such file or directory
   20 | #include "custom_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/wwl/test_ws/src/build/custom_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp/custom_interfaces/msg/detail/detected_object__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.hpp:11,
                 from /home/wwl/test_ws/src/build/custom_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp/custom_interfaces/msg/detail/dds_fastrtps/detected_object__type_support.cpp:4:
/home/wwl/test_ws/src/build/custom_interfaces/rosidl_generator_cpp/custom_interfaces/msg/detail/detected_object__struct.hpp:20:10: fatal error: custom_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp: No such file or directory
   20 | #include "custom_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/custom_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.dir/build.make:86: CMakeFiles/custom_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.dir/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/custom_interfaces/msg/detected_object__type_support.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/custom_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.dir/build.make:91: CMakeFiles/custom_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.dir/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp/custom_interfaces/msg/detail/dds_fastrtps/detected_object__type_support.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:395: CMakeFiles/custom_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:343: CMakeFiles/custom_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
In file included from /home/wwl/test_ws/src/build/custom_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp/custom_interfaces/msg/detail/detected_object__type_support.cpp:12:
/home/wwl/test_ws/src/build/custom_interfaces/rosidl_generator_cpp/custom_interfaces/msg/detail/detected_object__struct.hpp:20:10: fatal error: custom_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp: No such file or directory
   20 | #include "custom_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/custom_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.dir/build.make:91: CMakeFiles/custom_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.dir/rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp/custom_interfaces/msg/detail/detected_object__type_support.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:369: CMakeFiles/custom_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2

Failed   <<< custom_interfaces [8.10s, exited with code 2]
```

Comment: Please don't share errors as screenshots: it blocks search engine indexing and makes it trickier to read the actual error. Also, can you clarify what you've tried, the layout of your package, and other helpful information that's currently missing?

Comment: I think sharing your package's CMakeLists.txt file would help. If not hard, sharing the node's code too would definitely help.